# groovy Catkin_make Error: could not find package configuration file

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently shifted from electric to groovy, and am still getting acclimated to the catkin build system. Whilst trying to catkin_make a package using the laser_assembler and laser_filter packages; catkin complains that cmake couldnt find the config files. Upon checking the folder of the packages, I found that these were using the older rosbuild system. I would appreciate some help in solving this... thank you!

heres the output:

---

```
user@comp:~/ros_workspace$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/ros_workspace
Source space: /home/user/ros_workspace/src
Build space: /home/user/ros_workspace/build
Devel space: /home/user/ros_workspace/devel
Install space: /home/user/ros_workspace/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/nix/ros_workspace/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/nix/ros_workspace/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/nix/ros_workspace/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/nix/ros_workspace/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/nix/ros_workspace/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~  - scan_assembler
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'scan_assembler'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(scan_assembler)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "laser_filters"
  with any of the following names:

    laser_filtersConfig.cmake
    laser_filters-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "laser_filters" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "laser_filters_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "laser_filters" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scan_assembler/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62628/groovy-catkin_make-error:-could-not-find-package-configuration-file/) by [PratikSen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4880/pratiksen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

laser_filters is still using rosbuild and has not yet been migrated to catkin. Therefore you can not depend on that package from within a catkin package. Dependencies can only go from rosbuild to catkin - not the other way around.

You could poke the maintainer of laser_filters to migrate to catkin rather sooner than later. Until that has happened you can only use it from other rosbuild packages.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2